# Slow traversal times through Titan. How to improve the performance given the specific use case?

Tags: performance, graph, titan

I have recently just started trying out Titan and don't know how to improve performance if possible. For a simple benchmark use case we constructed, we set up users, each with there own posts. Currently, we have 20 users and spread out between all of them, 580 posts in the benchmarking data. Our actual application is very dynamic, therefore some configurations might not apply, which I will mention later on.

Before actual insertion, I create a property index on the unique identifier of the data (user / posts), which in this case, is the key name, "name". As well, auto key/label creation is set on, so creation of other properties / labels is permitted.

`g.makeKey('name').dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).unique().make()`

After creating the index, I insert users / posts vertices with edges between them indicating a said user created a said post.

Now to actual call the traversal. The specific query I want to do is given the list of user names / user vertices, find me all their posts. For example, given users with names 'user_1', 'user_2' and edge label 'user_posts_relationship'.

`g.V.copySplit(_().has('name', 'user_1'), _().has('name', 'user_2').exhaustMerge().out('user_posts_relationship')`

Now doing this given the entire 20 users in our fake data, it roughly takes 2 seconds. Is this bad performance given the number of posts? Is this the way I should do the traversal given a list of starting vertices? The reason why I don't use the MultiVertexQuery helper is because due to our actual application, we do not know how much edges we need to jump, and from my research, MultiVertexQuery only goes down one level.

Our current specs are the following:

- Titan 0.4.4
- Cassandra 2.0.9
- 1 CPU / 512 MB
- Ubuntu

Sorry for my mistakes if I am making any and would love to get assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the name property is already indexed. `copySplit` will not use the index, try this instead:

```
g.V().has('name', T.in, ['user_1', 'user_2']).out('user_posts_relationship')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did see some sort of performance increase. I do not know much about Titan, but as of right now, i will make this the right answer :). If there are any other comments from you (or any others) on increasing performance given this use case, please post an answer here!